# Is there any network capture application which capture specified software?

Tags: networking, wireshark, network-traffic

I`ve an application which has a lot of transaction with a lot of destination IP. Now, I want to capture all network traffic of this application.
I tried to capture these transaction by wireshark but wireshark capture all network traffic.
Can any application to capture network traffic of specified application?
Or can i filtered wireshark captured log by specified application?

Comment: You can apply various filters in Wireshark to capture only the relevant data. http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters

Answer (score 0):

To be able to filter a group of network connections, you'll need to identify something unique to the group.

E.g., Do all the connections to the different destination IPs use TCP and are they made to the same Server TCP port ?

If so, you could filter on the source IP and the destination TCP port.

And so on.

If there's nothing particularly distinct about the set of connections you wish to see, then one possibility might to exclude traffic which can't be part of the group.

TCP and not (dest==IP or dest==IP or dest==IP) ...

Note: the above filter is just pseudocode; it is *not* an actual valid filter.

Comment: I don't know any information of destination IPs, they change server on any transaction and I can not filter by destination. I can not filter source IP too because I run it on my PC and it is connected to network and has a lot of transaction. In wireshark don't exist any feature to filter by application name or service name.